# googleota directory on SD what is it? A duplication of DCIM folder, or else?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, camera, gallery, file-management

In my Android device I set the default location of file (photos, video, etc.) to be saved to SD memory card. Recently I had some problems with my phone/SD-card and did a backup of the SD files to my PC.

I noticed that there is a `googleota` directory that seems to be a duplicate of DCIM (I also noticed two "Camera" albums in Gallery as well). What's the purpose of the `googleota` directory on my SD card? Can I delete it safely?

EDIT:
I decided to delete the `googleota` folder from SD-card and now there's only one "Camera" album in Gallery (that's good as the second one was only a duplicate). Then, after little time, `googleota` folder has been created again in my SD-card... Anybody knows what that directory is intended for?

Comment: what Android device is this? And show a screenshot of the contents of your SD Card.

Comment: @Mark Yisri : Archos smartphone (not so new model). Too late for screenshots, I just deleted "googleota" folder : the duplicate "camera" album on Gallery is gone and everything else seems not having troubles. (Anyway "googleota" folder contained 4 folders that were .thumbnails, 100ANDRO, browser-images and Camera)

Comment: then delete the question, if no one can help you

Comment: @Mark Yisri I think there is still an unanswered point here: what's the purpose of "googleata" folder on Android? (And I think someone still can help too)

Comment: never seen it before